# How can I improve the performance of the Symfony Serializer?

Tags: php, json, symfony, serialization

I try to get a json variable from my database:

```
$table = $this->em->getRepository('App\\Entity\\Data')->findAll();
$encoders = [new JsonEncoder()]; 
$normalizers = [new DateTimeNormalizer(array('datetime_format' => 'd.m.Y')), new ObjectNormalizer($classMetadataFactory)];
$serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);

$groupsArray = $serializerGroups->getSerializerGroups($slug);
    $groups = $groupsArray['groups'];
    if( $groups != null) {
      $context['groups'] = $groups;
    }


$output = $serializer->serialize($table, 'json', $context);

dump($output);
```

The page loads really long until I see the result of output.
How can I make it faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really depends on the output you need it takes too long because in my opinion you have nested attribute in your DATA entity to make it faster use serialisation groups https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#component-serializer-attributes-groups-annotations and for a faster output avoid using findAll *you can use your repository and select data you need* and finally you can use the cache component to store your ouptut for a period of time